# Save image from io.BytesIO

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to convert some code in flask to normal terminal executable python code. But I have come across a certain section of code that tries to return an image as the response to that API call and I would like to store that image.

```
_, buffer = cv2.imencode('.jpg', img2)

return send_file(
             io.BytesIO(buffer),
             mimetype='image/jpeg',
             as_attachment=True,
             attachment_filename='image.jpg')
```

How do I re write this part so that I can save it as 'image.jpg'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Throw all the code away and just use:

```
cv2.imwrite('image.jpg', img2)
```

Comment: _"Throw all the code away and just use..."_ Coworkers always get kind of upset, when I tell them that. ;-)

Comment: @HansHirse I tell it like it is ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I have to contribute to Mark Setchell:
I you want to save jpg with quality setting, just use:

```
cv2.imwrite('image.jpg', img2, [int(cv2.IMWRITE_JPEG_QUALITY), 100])
```